# Including rmarkdown/html text in flexdashboard

Tags: r, markdown, flexdashboard

I have the following problem. In my `flexdashboard` app, I have a column tabset, like this:

````
Column {.tabset}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
### plot

```{r}
plot(x) ## example
```

### description

```{r child, child='MicMen.md'}
```
````

And the results should be: in the first tabset, a plot, and in the second, the description of this plot, that I wrote in .md (containing the equation, applications, etc).

What is happening is that the text is appearing side-by-side with the plot, instead of in the respective tab, and its not html. The 'description' tab is empty.

Any ideas to help me?

Answer (score 4):

Use the includeMarkdown function. It should be something like:

````
```{r}
includeMarkdown('MicMen.md')
```
````